# Show another div during form input hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple search bar animation, more specifically, when hovering over the bar, the search history pops up. However, when I try .search-bar-input:hover + .search-history, code doesn't work. I'm new to html, so it's possible it's a basic bug - but I can't find an answer anywhere

```
<div class="search-bar">
    <form class="search-form" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" class="search-bar-input" name="search-request" placeholder="Type here..." required minlength="4" maxlength="32">
    </form>
    <div class="search-history">
        search history
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.search-bar-input
{
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}

.search-bar-input:hover
{
    border: solid 2px lightgrey;
    outline: none;
}

.search-history
{
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
}

.search-bar-input:hover + .search-history
{
    display: block;
}

.search-history:hover
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Change the line `.search-bar-input:hover + .search-history` to `.search-form:hover + .search-history`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried displaying the website using different web browsers with the same result? Are you using an older web browser?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Different coding can behave differently depending on the web browser. This was just a tip not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your code when you are hovering the form, not the input field

```css
.search-bar-input {
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}

.search-bar-input:hover {
  border: solid 2px lightgrey;
  outline: none;
}

.search-history {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
}

.search-form:hover+.search-history {
  display: block;
  /* color: red; */
}

.search-history:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <form class="search-form" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" class="search-bar-input" name="search-request" placeholder="Type here..." required minlength="4" maxlength="32">
  </form>
  <div class="search-history">
    search history
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
.search-bar-input
{
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}

.search-bar-input:hover
{
    border: solid 2px lightgrey;
    outline: none;
}

.search-history
{
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
}

.search-bar:hover .search-history
{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
    <form class="search-form" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" class="search-bar-input" name="search-request" placeholder="Type here..." required minlength="4" maxlength="32">
    </form>
    <div class="search-history">
        search history
    </div>
</div>
```

It will affect `.search-history` when you hover `.search-bar`